# In Highcharts, how to move annotations along with the chart when it changes?

Tags: jquery, highcharts, annotations

Does Highcharts allows you the capability to ensure the annotations move along with the chart when it is resized (necessary if the chart is shown on smaller screens, or if it is the highlighted chart). If so, can someone please show me how this can be done as I need this for one my requirement.

Here's the code for the annotations that I have:

```
chart: {
  type: 'bubble',
  zoomType: 'xy',
  events: {
    load() {
      const chart = this;
      chart.renderer.text('&#x2190; More Disruptive', 290, 20)
      .attr({ zIndex: 10 })
      .css({ fontSize: '12px', color: '#666666'})
      .add();
      chart.renderer.text('Less Disruptive &#x2192;', 440, 20)
      .attr({ zIndex: 10 })
      .css({ fontSize: '12px', color: '#666666'})
      .add();
      chart.renderer.text('Greatly Decreased &#x2191;', 685, 140)
      .attr({ zIndex: 10 })
      .css({ fontSize: '12px', color: '#666666'})
      .add();
      chart.renderer.text('Greatly Increased &#x2193;', 688, 205)
      .attr({ zIndex: 10 })
      .css({ fontSize: '12px', color: '#666666'})
      .add();
    }
  }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/samwhite/jy4dcwb7/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you link an annotation to a point: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/sfo3L704/
or attach it to a mock point point: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/4ouwn19j/ it will be responsive.

```
    annotations: [{
        labels: [{
            point: {
                xAxis: 0,
                yAxis: 0,
                x: 3,
                y: 6
            }
        }]
    }]
```

In other case, you will need to calculate annotation's position after every resize (use for example `chart.redraw` event).

---

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/annotations.labels.point

Comment: Thank you ppotaczek.